# Changes have been merged from develop to main but are always visible when creating Pull request from develop to main

Tags: git, azure-devops, gitlab-ci, github-actions

We are maintaining the code in Azure Devops repository . It has 2 branches : main and develop .I am facing one issue that after merging my develop changes to main branch , I am seeing the same differences between main and develop . Merge has also been completed successfully but still we are seeing those differences .

This has caused lot of issues in raising the pull requests . Is it possible to fix this ?

Comment: What branching strategy are you using?

Comment: The strategy that we are following is : We are developing on develop and merging to main .

Comment: @AyushiGupta what do you mean by "same differences between main and develop"? Is it possible to post additional information? If you merge `develop` into `main`, assuming `develop` was a superset of `main`, you should get nothing when running `git diff` against the two branches, as merging them would make them equivalent in terms of content.

Comment: The problem is initially we had few commits on master which are not there on develop branch . So, we have resolved the conflicts and merged the changes to main . Whenever we create PR from develop to main , we always get same set of changes visible in PR , even though changes have already been merged to master .

Comment: It sounds like you didn't merge the conflict fix commit(s) into the develop branch? Try pulling changes into develop from main.